# Is there a smarter/better way to do HTTPS / WWW Rewrites?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I wrote an `.htaccess` script that appears to work.  However I'm new to Apache and often times I find out later that something I put together should have been constructed differently or with better semantics.

The goal of my code is to make sure that `www` and `HTTPS` are always present in the url.  I'm using 302 for testing purposes.  Put simply is this code jacked up?  Is there something painfully obvious that I should change?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

To enforce https and www , you can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

This will redirect **http://example.com** or **https://example.com** to **https://www.example.com**

Comment: Interesting.  Will it rewrite if a user types `example.com` and nothing else?